# IAM Policy Resource Pattern Error With Conditionals

Tags: amazon-iam

i'm scratching my head with this one i'm attempting to write an AWS Policy that'll basically constrict a (terraform) user to work in one specific region so that any accidental changes etc are kept to a minimum and the chances of accidentally hurting another environment are reduced. Keeping in mind that some services like IAM etc span outside of a region i've come up with a rudimentary one here, only problem is AWS is throwing the following error:

> This policy contains the following error: The following resources are invalid. They must be either '*' or an arn pattern: arn:aws:iam:*,arn:aws:route53:* For more information about the IAM policy grammar, see AWS IAM Policies

Here's a copy of the policy thus far, any help would be appreciated.:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "*",
        "NotResource": [
            "arn:aws:iam:*",
            "arn:aws:route53:*"
         ],
         "Condition": {
            "ForAnyValue:StringEquals": {
                "aws:RequestedRegion": "us-west-1"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "*",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:iam:*",
            "arn:aws:route53:*"
        ]
    }
]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this one :

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1595231481806",
      "Action": "route53:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "aws:RequestedRegion": "us-west-1"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1595231501844",
      "Action": "iam:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "aws:RequestedRegion": "us-west-1"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```